# What does sh -c "ps -l" mean in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sh, ps

My Command Interpreter is bash shell.After opening terminal on my OS(cent OS), I have executed following commands:

**scenario 1**

```
$sh -c "ps -l"
UID   PID   PPID TIME       CMD
3038  2577  2504 00:00:00   bash
3038  2992  2577 00:00:00    ps
```

**scenario 2**

```
$sh    
$ps -l
UID   PID   PPID TIME       CMD
3038  2577  2504 00:00:00   bash
3038  3005  2577 00:00:00    sh
3038  3006  3005 00:00:00    ps
```

Observe PID and PPID of `ps`.
In scenario 1, I am executing `ps -l` command on `sh` shell. So it's parent should be `sh` i.e., it's PPID should be PID of `sh`. But `ps -l` command listing that it's parent is `bash`. I am not understanding what is happening exactly. I am understanding the difference between **scenario 1** and **scenario 2**. But when I am executing the same commands on another OS(ubuntu), I am getting same listing under `ps -l` in **scenario 3** and **scenario 4**, as below:

**scenario 3**

```
$sh    
$ps -l
UID   PID   PPID TIME       CMD
3038  2577  2504 00:00:00   bash
3038  2991  2577 00:00:00    sh
3038  2992  2991 00:00:00    ps
```

**scenario 4**

```
$sh    
$ps -l
UID   PID   PPID TIME       CMD
3038  2577  2504 00:00:00   bash
3038  3005  2577 00:00:00    sh
3038  3006  3005 00:00:00    ps
```

Here in both scenarios, I am getting PPID of `ps` CMD as PID of `sh`.  What is happening exactly. Is my interpretation wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you type a command, bash just `fork` then `execve` the command. scenario 3 and scenario 4 are the case.

While `sh -c 'ps -l'` depends on shells.

On my linux distribution, the result of `` ls -l `which sh` `` is`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct  6 14:06 /usr/bin/sh -> bash`.

When `-c` is present, bash `execve` the following command directly. While another shell like `fish` does not.

`fish -c 'ps -l'`

`F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000   711   710  0  80   0 -  5707 wait   pts/5    00:00:00 bash
0 S  1000  1519   711  0  80   0 -  7054 wait   pts/5    00:00:00 fish
0 R  1000  1526  1519  0  80   0 -  9266 -      pts/5    00:00:00 ps`

What `execve` does is replacing the current process image with a new process image.`fork` creates a new process.